# How populate select box in edit page using rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have this in my form:

```
<%= f.select :status, options_for_select(Article::STATUS), :include_blank => true, :selected => @article.status, :class => 'select_field' %>
```

Model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :author, :content, :publication_date, :status, :title, :tag_tokens
  attr_reader :tag_tokens

  STATUS = ['Rascunho', 'Em Revisão', 'Publicado']

end
```

Why does not populate the field?

Comment: How do you initialize *f*? Is it an object form, or just a form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can simply pass an array in `[#select][1]`. You don't need to call options for collection. I also think you can ommit the `:selected` option if this is a model form, Rails will figure it out using the attribute value.

Try this:

```
<%= f.select :status, Article::STATUS, :include_blank => true, :class => 'select_field' %>
```